# php random int generator with seed

Tags: php

i have a randomgenerator which gnerate everytime the same output when the same seed is entered. But i get very often the same result. I want every result only once. The Random int generator generates less then 20 different numbers. How can i make the random number generator better?

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $random = random_int(0,999999999999999);
    header('Location: ?r='.$random.'');
}
class Random {
    private static $RSeed = 0;
    public static function seed($s = 0) {
        self::$RSeed = abs(intval($s)) % 9999999 + 1;
        self::num();
    }
    public static function num($min = 0, $max = 9999999) {
        if (self::$RSeed == 0) self::seed(mt_rand());
        self::$RSeed = (self::$RSeed * 125) % 2796203;
        return self::$RSeed % ($max - $min + 1) + $min;
    }

}
$double[] = array();
$return ="";
if(isset($_GET["r"])){
    Random::seed($_GET["r"]);
    $x= 0;
    while($x < 50){
        $random = Random::num(1, 1200) . '<br />';
        foreach($double as $val){
            if($val == $random){
                $return = "true";
            }
        }
        if(!($return == "true")){
            echo $random;
            $double[] = $random;
            $x++;
        }
    } 
}else{
    $random = random_int(0,999999999999999);
    header('Location: ?r='.$random.'');
}
?>
```

Comment: `rand` is not a random function. you want PHP 7 function [`random_int`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) for secure randomness.

Comment: Is there any good reason that you wrote your own random number generator? Usually, that is not that easy to do if you are looking for a **really** random behaviour

Comment: i just need a randomgenerator with a seed.

Comment: Can you give more info about "But i get very often the same result" What is "very often", and with which numbers are you getting same results? When i look at your script i only see "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded...on line 29"

Answer (score -1):

If you want a random and non-repeating sequence, try range and shuffle functions

```
$random_sequence = range($min, $max);
mt_srand($seed); # Use srand in php 5
shuffle($random_sequence);
```

Answer (score -1):

There are so many ways generating numbers with seed.

Here is my way to get a 32 bit random number by seed based on [Lehmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_random_number_generator) algorithm. This is very useful for real procedural generation.

Get a random number with seed of 1000

```php
$random = lcg_rand(1000);
```

> 576869358

Use modulo to force a range 0-256

```php
$random = lcg_rand(1000) % 256;
```

> 238

Here is the function you can call:

```php
function lcg_rand(int $seed = 1): int {
    return ($seed + 1) * 279470273 % 0xfffffffb;
}
```